# KeyDown() ,sendKeys() not working in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to type a string in capital letters (using KeyDown) into amazon.in website search bar using `sendKeys()` but I don't see the text on the search bar. I don't see any error. I use debug mode then I also I can find any error.

Question:

- How can I resolve this?
- How can I debug it myself and find issue?

For debug I put a breakpoint on below line and then use step over option to run each line.
`mouseAction.moveToElement(elementLocation).build().perform();`

```
public class MouseActions {

  public static void main (String [] args){
    System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\tokci\\Documents\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");

    Actions mouseAction = new Actions(driver);

    //this mouse action works
    WebElement elementLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']"));
    mouseAction.moveToElement(elementLocation).build().perform();

            //below code does not work
    WebElement keysLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));       
    mouseAction.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(keysLocation).sendKeys("shoes").build().perform();

  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `keysLocation.sendKeys("shoes")` ???

Comment: or `keysLocation.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, "shoes")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keysLocation` is a `input` element here you can use `.sendKeys()` without using `mouseAction` as below and it works :-

```
keysLocation.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, "shoes");
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Saurabh Gaur - this worked but I don't understand on thing. void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend) is the method definition... which means it can accept only char sequence as its arguement.....how do I know if it can also expect 2 arguments e.g. sendKeys( keys.SHIFT, "shoes" ) ???

Comment: @Tokci It's clearly says the method that it expect `java.lang.CharSequence... ` as input which means it wants an array of `CharSequence` means like `CharSequence[]`, in java `...` means `[]` in args..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `click` before you use `sendKeys`. `moveToElement` function just moves the cursor over and `.click()` function will ensure that the element has been selected

Try this

```
WebElement keysLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));       
mouseAction.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(keysLocation).click().sendKeys("shoes").build().perform();
```

Comment: Alright. I just tried the line you've written:
`mouseAction.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(keysLocation).sendKeys("shoes").build().perform();` and even `mouseAction.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("shoes").build().perform();` and they worked in one of my projects containing a textbox. Nevertheless, I second the solution provided by @Saurabh Gaur

Answer (score 0):

firefox driver does not respond to keydown command.

so my work around was not use actions class.  Here's example of code:

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT + "big");